# Find the minimum value of $|x-2|+|2x+1|-|x-1|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Find the minimum value of 
$$|x-2|+|2x+1|-|x-1|$$

My way of doing it

$|x|$ is also known as distance of x from the origin

$|x-2|$ distance from the origin will be $2$

$|2x+1|$ distance from the origin will be $-1/2$

$|x-1|$ distance from the origin will be $1$

Now in order to find the minimum value, I assumed that on the number line.

Suppose $A=2$, $B=-1/2$ and $C=1$ are friends. Now they all want to meet at a point on the number line where minimum distance is covered. That minimum point will be 1.

Now in order to find the minimum value, I know A will cover $1 unit$ to reach C and B will cover $3/2 \text{ units }$ to reach C.

Total distance covered is $5/2$. But, the correct answer is 1. What is wrong in my way of doing it?

Comment: I edited your post to make it easier for users to read and follow your solution.  If you object to the edit, you can roll back to the original post, or you can ask me to roll it back for you.

Comment: No, its okay @amWhy

Comment: I don't understand your line of reasoning, but note that the function to minimize grows to infinity as $x \to \pm \infty$ and is linear away from the points $x=-1/2,1,2$, so that the minimum has to occur at one of those three points.

Comment: Just checking, the coefficient of $|x-1|$ is $-1$ rather than $1$ right?

Answer (score 1):

The value of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ is minimal belong the set $A=\{2,-1/2,1\}$ (these values are the values such that vanish each module individually). But $f(2)=f(1)=4$ and $f(-1/2)=1$, thus the minimal value of function is $1$.

Comment: Why does $f(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ impossible?

Comment: I agree that we have to check to make sure it doesn't go to $-\infty$.  For example, the question could have been $|x-2|-|2x+1|-|x-1|$.

Answer (score 0):

Your working is about minimizing

$$|x-2|+\left|x+\frac12\right|+|x-1|.$$

In that case, each term is indeed a distance and you are minimizing a sum of distance. Modeling of imagining $3$ friends picking up a common meeting place to minimize total travel distance holds.

However, if your question is

$$|x-2|+\left|2x+1\right|+|x-1|,$$

then you have to imagine that you have $4$ friends as the question now can be viewed as

$$|x-2|+2\left|x+\frac12\right|+|x-1|=|x-2|+\left|x+\frac12\right|+\left|x+\frac12\right|+|x-1|$$

If your question is indeed

$$|x-2|+\left|2x+1\right|-|x-1|,$$

then we can adopt Alex Provost's suggestion by examining those $3$ points. In that case, we can't visualize it as a sum of distance, in fact, the more the person at $1$ travel, the smaller is the overall value and the modeling of minimizing of sum of travel distance falls apart.

Comment: It's -|x-1| and not |x+1|. @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: I see. then your modeling of friends meeting wouldn't work.

Comment: Why? @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: your whole argument is about minimizing the total distance of $3$ friends have to travel right. total distance is of the form of $|x-a|+|x-b|+|x-c|$ rather than $|x-a|+|x-b|-|x-c|$.  In fact it seems that $a$ and $b$ are friends who want $c$ to exercise (travel) more and minimizes their own travel distance.

Comment: Then what is going to work in this case? @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: just examine the $3$ points as suggested by Alex Provost. He was careful in checking that the function goes to $\infty$ and $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. You might like to plot out the graph to see that there are kinks at those points and interesting things happen at those points.

Answer (score 0):

We evaluate $f(x):=|x-2|+|2x+1|-|x-1|$ in two stages. First,
 $$|x-2|-|x-1| =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if }\qquad\;\; x<1, \\
 3-2x & \text{if} \quad 1\leqslant x\leqslant2,\\
-1 & \text{if}\quad2<x.
\end{cases}$$
Now add in the other term $|2x+1|$ to get
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-2x & \text{if} \;\,\qquad\quad x<-\tfrac12,\\
2x+2  & \text{if }  -\tfrac12\leqslant x<1, \\
 4 & \text{if} \qquad 1\leqslant x\leqslant2,\\
2x & \text{if}\qquad2<x.
\end{cases}$$
Clearly, $f(x)$ is decreasing below $x=-\frac12$ and increasing above it; so the minimum is at $x=-\frac12$, when $f(x)=1$.